# Output election winner in the presence of ties

Tags: java, output

I have programmed a working voting system, but it needs a little more decision making involved. The program needs to work if **two or more** candidates have the same number of votes.

Below is what i have but i think it is very long winded, and it will only work with 2 candidates having the same number of votes. Is there a more efficient way of doing this while working with 2 or more candidates having the same votes.

There are only 5 candidates available in this scenario, but should work if more are added too.

```html
        if(numArray[0] == numArray[1]){
            System.out.println("\nIn third place: " + Array[3]);
            System.out.println("In second place: " + Array[2]);
            System.out.println("And the winner is: " + Array[0] + " and " + Array[1]);

        }else if(numArray[1] == numArray[2]){
            System.out.println("\nIn third place: " + Array[3]);
            System.out.println("In second place: " + Array[1] + " and " + Array[2]);
            System.out.println("And the winner is: " + Array[0]);
        }else if(numArray[2] == numArray[3]){
            System.out.println("\nIn third place: " + Array[2] + " and " + Array[3]);
            System.out.println("In second place: " + Array[1]);
            System.out.println("And the winner is: " + Array[0]);
        }else{
            System.out.println("\third place: " + Array[2]);
            System.out.println("second place: " + Array[1]);
            System.out.println("winner is: " + Array[0]);
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand how `numArray` works, is it the amount of votes for the name at that same index? Can you give an example of an input with its expected output?

Comment: I have editted the code with everything so you can see.

Comment: @CyberJack2022 Unfortunately your edit deleted the *actually relevant* code. Please revert it. Also, please take a moment to read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) — you are accidentally inserting a JavaScript block instead of a Java code block

Comment: None of that is javascript

Comment: @CyberJack2022 I know. But it is *formatted* as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first check what are the scores, highest, second highest, third highest.
And then pick the names which have these values

```
public static void displayFinalResults(String[] stringArray, int[] numArray){
    int highestScore = max(numArray, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    int secondHighestScore = max(numArray, highestScore);
    int thirdHighestScore = max(numArray, secondHighestScore);

    System.out.println("\nIn third place: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
        if (numArray[i] == thirdHighestScore) {
            System.out.println(stringArray[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("In second place: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
        if (numArray[i] == secondHighestScore) {
            System.out.println(stringArray[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("And the winner: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
        if (numArray[i] == highestScore) {
            System.out.println(stringArray[i]);
        }
    }

}

public static int max(int[] scores, int lessThan) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int score : scores) {
        if (score > max && score < lessThan) {
            max = score;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: i already have a sort algorithm that sorts the array of highest to lowest. But i need something that will do the question i asked. Which is allowing two or more to have the same answer and be placed in the ranks. e.g. ahmed and celine win. jack and joe come second etc

Comment: This code does that, you can have 2 persons on the same rank. Try it out.

Comment: i accidentally edited the code and it changed the for loop to for(int score : scores). What was it originally do you know? @Bentaye

Comment: @CyberJack2022 Seems correct, that is what it should be `for (int score : scores)`

Comment: what does it mean in say these terms for (int i = 0 ; i > 10; i++)?

Comment: it was previously something else. and i changed it accidentally in my IDE. and i prefer it that way as it doesnt make sense to me this way lol

Comment: @CyberJack2022 `for (int score : scores)` is he same as `for (int i; i<scores.length; i++) { int score = scores[i]; ...... }` . You should learn how to use it, you will see it everywhere and you will be probably be asked to use it in code reviews

Answer (score 0):

This is approach I would take. I would create a structure to hold the candidate name and number of votes as tracking that across 2 arrays is complicated and might be confusing. I would also suggest to use different data structures than arrays as the method input, I converted the input in the example into stream of `Candidate` which has 2 fields name and numVotes:

```java
    record Candidate(String name, int numVotes) {
    }

    public static void displayFinalResults(String[] stringArray, int[] numArray) {
        //make sure that 2 arrays match in size
        assert numArray.length == stringArray.length;
        //zip arrays and convert to the stream of Candidate
        var candidates = IntStream.range(0, stringArray.length).mapToObj(i -> new Candidate(stringArray[i], numArray[i]));
        //group by number of votes
        var groupedByNumVotes = candidates.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.numVotes));
        //sort by number of votes descending
        var sorded = groupedByNumVotes.entrySet().stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e2.getKey(), e1.getKey()));
        //take first 3 places
        var winners = sorded.limit(3).toList();

        //Loop through the list of winners with index and print it
        for (int i = 0; i < winners.size(); i++) {
            //List is indexed from 0 so the place number needs to be increased by one
            System.out.println("Place " + (i + 1));  
            winners.get(i).getValue().forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this javascript?

Comment: As to be honest, i dont really understand the program too.

Comment: it's java 17. I left the comments, what do you need to explain more in detail?

Comment: the'record Candidate' part. I dont understand how that works with the program. and also the rest of the code i dont understand as i havent learnt java 17. I also have to create functions from scratch like i have in the above code. if that helps.

Comment: the record keyword was introduced in Java 14, it allows you to create a immutable structure with the defined fields, in this case name and numVotes and implements all the boilerplate like equals, hasshcode , toString for you

Comment: the java version i am using is earlier than this i think. not too sure. But i have not learnt that feature yet, so my mentor would not allow it

Comment: you can always implement it as a regular class with all the clutter. the point I wanted to make, is that it's cleaner when you model your domain instead of tracking the names and number of votes across multiple arrays, which is hard to work with and also error prone

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with your approach (except that, by convention, the second place is usually skipped if there is a tie for the first; that is: there are two tied first-place candidates and a third place, but no second place). You just need to add one more case for three tied candidates.

That said, you can slightly shorten the code by merging redundancies in output formatting:

```
public static void displayFinalResults(String[] names, int[] scores) {
    final String[] winners = new String[3];

    if (scores[0] == scores[1] && scores[1] == scores[2]) {
        winners[0] = String.format("%s, %s and %s", names[0], names[1], names[2]);
    } else if (scores[0] == scores[1]) {
        winners[0] = String.format("%s and %s", names[0], names[1]);
        winners[2] = names[2];
    } else if (scores[1] == scores[2]) {
        winners[0] = names[0];
        winners[1] = String.format("%s and %s", names[1], names[2]);
    } else {
        System.arraycopy(names, 0, winners, 0, 3);
    }

    System.out.println();
    if (winners[2] != null) System.out.printf("In third place: %s\n", winners[2]);
    if (winners[1] != null) System.out.printf("In second place: %s\n", winners[1]);
    final String prefix = winners[2] == null && winners[1] == null ? "T" : "And t";
    System.out.printf("%she winner is: %s\n", prefix, winners[0]);
}
```

Comment: i appreciate the help, but in my scenario this would not be correct.

Comment: @CyberJack2022 Fair enough, but it should be trivial to adapt. Just the assign the corresponding `winner` index.